# Why is my jQuery toggle only changing classes in one direction?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, nav

I guess there is something really simple wrong here, but I can't figure it out. The class names are obviously right otherwise it wouldn't load in the first place I guess, so I can't see why it won't switch back on the second click.

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="nav">
    <div class="drawer">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="drawerOpener">
    <i class="material-icons" value="Switch Class">menu</i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,600,400italic,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.drawer-closed {
    width: 370px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: -370px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f7f7f;
}

.drawer {
    width: 370px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f7f7f;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0em 0em 1em 1em;
    font-family: Open Sans, Sans Serif;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

ul li:first-child {
    padding-top: 1em;
}

#drawerOpener {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```

jQuery

```
  $(function() {
    $('#drawerOpener').click(function() {
        $(".drawer").toggleClass("drawer drawer-closed",'normal');
        return false;
    });
  });
```

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/chris86/pen/yeOvOe

Comment: You should have tagged question with jQuery UI too, because jQuery `toggleClass()` and UI one have different sig

Comment: ah thanks, I'll change that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you remove the `drawer` class on the first click. On the second click there is no `.drawer` element to select. If you change you logic so that only the `.drawer-closed` class is toggled the code works fine:

```
$('#drawerOpener').click(function() {
    $(".drawer").toggleClass("drawer-closed");
    return false;
});
```

```css
.drawer {
    width: 370px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #7f7f7f;
}

.drawer.drawer-closed {
    margin-left: -370px;
}
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obxEpM)

Comment: @A.Wolff I removed the `normal` parameter on the `toggleClass` call as it's incorrect. The second parameter of `toggleClass` should be a boolean no matter which library you're calling: http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/, http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/. Providing a string of 'normal' means it will always be passing `true`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you explain a bit more in your answer about the logic i.e. I understand how removing the other class was the problem but I don't quite understand how adding a second class attached to the first one helped. Also...if I keep the 'normal' in it moves it off the screen smoothly, how come it is incorrect but seems to provide some function?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, op is using jQuery UI [toggleClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) here. See my comment under question, i get fooled too ;)

Comment: @Chris The second class is required to actually hide the `.drawer` element by setting `margin-left: -370px;`.

Comment: @A.Wolff I linked that one too - the second param is `switch` which takes a boolean. I'm confused if it has the effect of making an animation though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ya, not sure, i don't use jQuery UI so... :

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".drawer").toggleClass("drawer drawer-closed",'normal');
```

you toggle the class "drawer" on the first click, so it will be removed.
on the second click it won´t find the class ".drawer" because it´s removed on the first click.

use another class without style for the selection of the element

Comment: This line of code is the same as the original question...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The important part is the explaination :)

Comment: The solution is probably `$(".drawer").toggleClass("drawer-closed", 'normal');`